How can I add a Geometry attribute/ parameter to a Modifier Geometry Node and name it?
How can I give a name to a parameter of a Modifier Geometry Node?
I have read:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/geometry_nodes.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/groups.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/inspection.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/read/named_attribute.html
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/store_named_attribute.html

The one in Group Inputs cannot be named and also does not appear in the modifier.




I saw that I can add a named attribute/ parameter, but this does not offer to use a Geometry data type.




A "top-most" node tree can only use a single "Geometry" input, because the modifier will only pass a single geometry. Likewise with the output, because the modifier only expects one geometry output. If the node tree has more geometry inputs and/or outputs, they can be used in a different context - when a top-most node tree uses another node tree in a "custom group".
So the way you add those additional geometry inputs/outputs is either by using the interface in the N Numbers Panel:

Or by dragging from the empty "ghost" socket to a geometry socket:

But again, this won't be used by the modifier, because it just isn't implemented in the way to use this additional data in any way.
Perhaps you have some particular need, like keeping two geometries separate so a modifier after geonodes only affects one? If you explain your usecase we can advise with a workaround or just a better workflow.

Thanks for your answer. The use-case is that I want to calculate the distance between "this" and another geometry and calculate the size of the generated geometry based on that.
"This" geometry is something to read from and the "other" geometry are the eyes of an avatar.
I want to calculate the target size of the generated geometry in a way that it roughly matches the (sharp) field of view of the avatar.

@TorstenKnodt https://i.imgur.com/UXmf4Cv.png https://i.imgur.com/cUs4xry.gif

The first is what I had first, but this makes the node unreuseable. I would like to be able to use this also in other projects and/ or multiple times.

@TorstenKnodt like this? https://i.imgur.com/ilb9D5I.gif

Right, that's weird now. If you look, this is what I did, but the field for the new input did not appear.

@TorstenKnodt look at the color of the socket.
